# PHPUnit - define constants which store function results for all tests

Tags: constants, phpunit

I have a constant in my project:

```
define('HOME_DIR', dirname(__DIR__, 2));
```

PHPUnit doesn't see this constant, because it's not defined in XML configuration file, but I can define only string values, how can I use `dirname()` function as PHPUnit constant value?

Comment: It depends a lot in the framework you are using. Are you using a framework? If so, which one and what version?

Comment: I'm using, but it's self-written framework where I'm practicing)

Comment: so, now it depends on who is running `define('HOME_DIR', dirname(__DIR__, 2));` first, if that is your PHPUnit test, it should already be defined, hence it should be using your desired PHPUnit `dir`. What is the flow to initialize your framework and initialize a test?

Comment: I have `index.php` as entry point in `public` directory so when I'm trying to load the page, `index.php` requires `env.php` file with these constants and then runs application. PHPunit tests are stored in `tests` folder in root.

Comment: Could you add these 2 files content in your question?

Comment: I've managed to define this constant finally, the problem was in my custom bootstrap file which was developed only for web application.